# Apache server dies regularly in the middle of the night for no apparent reason

Tags: apache-2.4

My Apache 2.4.10 server has started to display erratic behavior: for 3rd time in row, it shuts down in the middle of the night, for no apparent reason.

```
$ service apache2 status
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─forking.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Pk 2020-05-15 00:09:03 UTC; 7h ago
  Process: 24771 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 10366 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 22659 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

mai 14 18:06:53 ip-172-30-0-106 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
mai 14 18:06:53 ip-172-30-0-106 apache2[22659]: Starting web server: apache2...g
mai 14 18:06:53 ip-172-30-0-106 apache2[22659]: [Thu May 14 18:06:53.412357 ...g
mai 14 18:06:54 ip-172-30-0-106 apache2[22659]: .
mai 14 18:06:54 ip-172-30-0-106 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
mai 15 00:09:03 ip-172-30-0-106 apache2[24771]: Stopping web server: apache2.
```

Here's excerpt from error.log around the 2020-05-15 00:09:03 UTC:

```
$ tail /var/log/apache2/error.log.1
[Fri May 15 00:08:59.195227 2020] [:error] [pid 22718] [client (IP:port removed)] script '/var/www/404/index.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri May 15 00:09:00.356207 2020] [:error] [pid 22683] [client (IP:port removed)] script '/var/www/404/index.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri May 15 00:09:03.100670 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 22674] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri May 15 00:09:11.467042 2020] [so:warn] [pid 24785] AH01574: module proxy_module is already loaded, skipping
[Fri May 15 00:09:11.467066 2020] [so:warn] [pid 24785] AH01574: module proxy_http_module is already loaded, skipping
[Fri May 15 00:09:11.487750 2020] [wsgi:warn] [pid 24786] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.8.
[Fri May 15 00:09:11.487766 2020] [wsgi:warn] [pid 24786] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.9.
[Fri May 15 00:09:11.492791 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 24786] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) OpenSSL/1.0.1t mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri May 15 00:09:11.492809 2020] [core:notice] [pid 24786] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri May 15 00:09:11.635360 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 24786] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

After such failure, it's enough to just `service apache2 start` and server keeps running, until next time. Apache2 processes start and shut down routinely, that is not unusual. But what can cause the server to go dead completely? Is there some other log where the situation around that time could be inspected further?

Comment: `caught SIGTERM` sounds like something is sending a signal to shut down. Check your crob jobs, logrotate would be my first candidate to investigate.

Comment: There is something stopping your server: `SIGTERM`, check your unit files, cronjob, etc.